# PHP: Оставить выбранные элементы массива без использования foreach()

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть два массива. Нужно оставить с первого массива лишь те элементы которые встречаются во втором. Как известно можно сделать это с помощью `in_array` внутри `foreach`:

```
$firstArray = array('A','B','C','D','E');
$secondArray = array('A','C','E','X','Y','Z');
$arrayOfResults = array();
foreach($firstArray  as $item) {
    if(in_array($arrayOfAllItems, $secondArray )) {
        $arrayOfResults[] = $item;
    }
}
echo implode(',',$arrayOfResults); // A, C, E
```

Но как можно получить `$arrayOfResults` без использования `foreach()` ? Например через `array_map()` или как то по-другому?

Comment: Просто любопытно, а чем вам не угодил `foreach`?

Comment: Если у вас **уже есть** массив элементов, ВЫБРАННЫХ среди элементов первого массива, зачем вам нужен еще один такой же массив - по сути его копия? Бессмыслица какая-то.

Comment: Во втором массиве есть элементы которых нету в первом. Нужно оставить с первого лишь те которые содержатся во втором. Обновил вопрос, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: @stckvrw http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php  поможет  ?  array_intersect — Вычисляет схождение массивов......Возвращает массив, содержащий все значения array1, которые существуют во всех переданных аргументах.

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Интересно, а зачем тогда `in_array()` придумали если одной строкой можно?

Comment: `in_array()` удобно будет в другой ситуации использовать. ситуации разные бывают.... эдакий своего рода `strpos` только в массиве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP есть функция поиска схождения массивов: `array_intersect`

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array(...);
$arr1 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

По итогу, первый массив оставляет себе только те элементы, которые есть и во втором, и в первом массивах.